# How to read values from a config file while building a project?

Tags: c#, wix

I have programmed a bootstrapper-project with WiX 3.8 and VS 2013 (C#).
In the project file You can create properties like that one for getting the build version from the EXE-file which shall be installed:

```
  <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
    <!-- Set the Variable BuildVersion -->
    <GetAssemblyIdentity AssemblyFiles="../FilesForSetup/MyApp.exe">
      <Output TaskParameter="Assemblies" ItemName="AsmInfo" />
    </GetAssemblyIdentity>
    <CreateProperty Value="%(AsmInfo.Version)">
      <Output TaskParameter="Value" PropertyName="BuildVersion" />
    </CreateProperty>
    <CreateProperty Value="$(DefineConstants)">
      <Output TaskParameter="Value" PropertyName="DefineConstantsOriginal" />
    </CreateProperty>
    <CreateProperty Value="$(DefineConstants);BuildVersion=$(BuildVersion)">
      <Output TaskParameter="Value" PropertyName="DefineConstants" />
    </CreateProperty>
  </Target>
```

Now i want to put some properties for a webserver login (url, user, pw) into a config file, read the properties while build and put them into project properties.
Can this be done and which type of config file would be the best choice (p.e. XML)?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it can be done and the best choice for the config file type is XML.
Per example you can write a config file for web server access like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<parameters>
  <parameter name="webserverurl" value="http://deviis.myCompany.net/release/" />
  <parameter name="webserveruser" value="administrator" />
  <parameter name="webserverpassword" value="myPassword" />
</parameters>
```

Then we define some varaibles in the bundle file:

```
<Variable Name="WebServerUrl"
          Value="$(var.WebServerUrl)"></Variable>
<Variable Name="WebServerUser"
          Value="$(var.WebServerUser)"></Variable>
<Variable Name="WebServerPassword"
          Value="$(var.WebServerPassword)"></Variable>
```

At least we have to insert a few lines in the bootstrapper project file to read the properties from the config and set the bundle variables.
Here just one example: the web server url

```
<XmlPeek Namespaces="&lt;Namespace Prefix='myNamespace' Uri='http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003'/&gt;" XmlInputPath="..\AppConfig\appconfig.xml" Query="/parameters/parameter[@name='webserverurl']/@value">
  <Output TaskParameter="Result" PropertyName="webserverurlResult" />
</XmlPeek>
<CreateProperty Value="$(webserverurlResult)">
  <Output TaskParameter="Value" PropertyName="WebServerUrlProp" />
</CreateProperty>
<CreateProperty Value="$(DefineConstants);WebServerUrl=$(WebServerUrlProp)">
  <Output TaskParameter="Value" PropertyName="DefineConstants" />
</CreateProperty>
```

At first we read the property with the XmlPeek-tag and put it into the property webserverurlResult.
Then we create the property WebServerUrlProp with the value webserverurlResult and put it into the bundle variable WebServerUrl.
Alternatively we don't have to create the property WebServerUrlProp.
A few lines less in our project file.
This would look like that:

```
<XmlPeek Namespaces="&lt;Namespace Prefix='myNamespace' Uri='http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003'/&gt;" XmlInputPath="..\AppConfig\appconfig.xml" Query="/parameters/parameter[@name='webserverurl']/@value">
  <Output TaskParameter="Result" PropertyName="webserverurlResult" />
</XmlPeek>
<CreateProperty Value="$(DefineConstants);WebServerUrl=$(webserverurlResult)">
  <Output TaskParameter="Value" PropertyName="DefineConstants" />
</CreateProperty>
```

Each time the bootstrapper project builds, it reads the properties from the config file and puts them into the bundle variables.
If you have a self-made UI, you can access the variable values like that:

```
UrlWebapi = Bootstrapper.Engine.StringVariables["WebServerUrl"];
```

UrlWebapi is in that case a property of type string.
I hope this helps.